# Подмена значения в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Возможно ли в php реализовать подмену значения в массиве? Есть два массива с идентичными ключами, но с разными значениями. К примеру если ключ массива1 равен ключу массив2 то совершить подмену значения из массива1 в массиве2.

Answer (score -1):

```
$langcn = array(

    'name' => '门户 文章广告',
    'desc' => '展现方式: 文章广告显示于文章页面，分为内容区域环绕广告和相关阅读上方广告 2 种。',

);

$langru = array (

    'name' => 'В содержании статей',
    'desc' => 'Режим показа: Объявления показываются сверху статей (2 типа)',

);


$newarr = array_replace($langru, $langcn);
print_r($newarr);
```

Comment: И смысл от этого?